# Trying to get Vector iterator to iterating in a different order

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

My question is twofold:

1. I have a vector of objects and a vector of integers, I want to iterate on my object vector in the order of the integer vector:

   meaning if `{water,juice,milk,vodka}` is my object vector and `{1,0,3,2}` is my integer vector I wish to have a const iterator for my object vector that will have juice for the first object, water for the second, vodka and last milk.

   is there a simple way of doing this?
2. suppose I have a function returning const iterator (itr) to a unknown (but accessible) vector 
   meaning, I can use  `(itr.getvalue())` but i don't have the size of the vector I'm iterating on, is there a way to make a while loop and know the end or the vector by iterator means?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 2):

**Question 1:**

Omitting most of the boilerplate needed for a proper iterator, the following is how it would work:

```
template<typename Container, typename Iterator>
class index_iterator
{
public:
  typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
  index_iterator(Container& c, Iterator iter):
    container(c),
    iterator(iter)
  {
  }
  value_type& operator*() { return container[*iterator]; }
  index_iterator& operator++() { ++iterator; return *this; }
  bool operator==(index_iterator const& other)
  {
    return &container == &other.container && iterator == other.iterator;
  }
  // ...
private:
  Container& container;
  Iterator iterator;
};

template<typename C, typename I>
 index_iterator<C, I> indexer(C& container, I iter)
{
  return index_iterator<C, I>(container, iter);
}
```

Then you could write e.g.

```
std::vector<std::string> vs;
std::vector<int> vi
// fill vs and vi
std::copy(indexer(vs, vi.begin()),
          indexer(vs, vi.end()),
          std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
```

**Question 2:**

No, it isn't possible.

Comment: And there it is. :) Except `s/\*begin/\*iterator/`. And you're going to need to support `C` being a template type, methinks...

Comment: Thanks for noting the iterator name error. There is no need to do something for `C` since class template instantiations are just ordinary classes.

Comment: Oh yes, you're passing an instantiation aren't you. OK.

Answer (score 0):

## 1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string>  foods{"water", "juice", "milk", "vodka"};
std::vector<unsigned int> indexes{1,0,3,2};

for (int i : indexes) { // ranged-for; use normal iteration if you must
   std::cout << foods[i] << " ";
}

// Output: juice water vodka milk
```

[Live demo](http://www.ideone.com/UkrNw)

If you really want to wrap this behaviour into a single iterator for `foods`, this can be done but it gets a bit more complicated.

---

## 2

> suppose I have a function returning const iterator (itr) to a unknown (but accessible) vector meaning, I can use (itr.getvalue()) but i don't have the size of the vector I'm iterating on, is there a way to make a while loop and know the end or the vector by iterator means?

If you don't have the vector for its size, and you don't have the vector's end iterator then, no, you can't. You can't reliably iterate over anything with just one iterator; you need a pair or a distance.

Answer (score 0):

Others have already covered number 1. For number 2, it basically comes down to a question of what you're willing to call an iterator. It's certainly possible to define a class that will do roughly what you're asking for -- a single object that both represents a current position and has some way of figuring out when it's been incremented as much as possible.

Most people would call that something like a `range` rather than an iterator though. You'd have to use it somewhat differently from a normal iterator. Most iterators are used by explicitly comparing them to another iterator representing the end of the range. In this case, you'd pass two separate positions when you created the "iterator" (one for the beginning/current position, the other for the end position) and you'd overload `operator bool` (for the most obvious choice) to indicate whether the current position had been incremented past the end. You'd use it something like: `while (*my_iterator++) operator_on(*my_iterator);` -- quite a bit different from using a normal iterator.

Answer (score -2):

> I wish to have a const iterator for my object vector that will have
>   juice for the first object

```
typedef std::vector<Drink> Drinks;
Drinks drinks;
drinks.push_back("water");
drinks.push_back("juice");
drinks.push_back("milk");
drinks.push_back("vodka");
Drinks::const_iterator i = drinks.begin();
```

> const iterator (itr) to a unknown (but accessible) vector

```
Drinks::const_iterator itr = some_func();
while (itr != drinks.end()) {
   doStuff;
   ++itr;
}
```

Comment: Mmm, no... That's a normal iteration. (a) You didn't provide `some_func`'s definition, which is what the OP wants; (b) there is no definition of `some_func` that can yield a `Drinks::const_iterator` that has different behaviour from any other `Drinks::const_iterator`.